# What's the best way to detect a deleted record?

Tags: mysql, json

This isn't really a question about some code I have not working, but rather I'm looking for guidance on how to solve a problem. Given any programming or scripting language with which you're familiar, how would you solve this problem:

You are given two sets of data: a JSON object that is retrieved from a remote system on a nightly basis, and a MySQL database that keeps track of the data within that JSON object. The JSON object may contain hundreds of records and the database tracks all of those individual records and also tracks any changes to those records. The order of the records within the JSON object also occasionally change. Each record has a UID associated with it in both the JSON object and in the MySQL database.

Occasionally, however, a record is deleted on this remote system. The JSON does not reflect this deletion by marking it as deleted or inactive in the object. Instead, this record is simply missing.

What is the best way to detect that there is a missing record, and precisely which record is missing, considering the fact that the ordering of the records in the JSON object may change night-to-night?

*edit*

Someone asked me what the application is. I'm a software developer at a university. I receive a nightly dump of student schedule data (JSON). I want to track changes in the schedule data and notify the students of changes in the schedule.

The MySQL database keeps a record of all of the events ever in the schedule, and it is currently around 10,000 records large.

*edit 2*

Essentially, given a master database and comparing it to a subset of that database, I'm looking for items missing from the subset.

Comment: hm, which dataset was broken? mysql or json?

Comment: No dataset is broken, per se, but the MySQL is static and only responds to changes in the JSON.

Comment: So, you need detect missed items in the JSON and delete it from database?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I don't want to delete the records but rather just mark them as inactive/deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to some arch changes)

If this impossible, you can use followed query for this

> UPDATE...WHERE UID NOT IN (list of UIDS)

long list, long query, but not very slow (Have you index by UID?)

Added:
Also you can store the last json(or UIDs only) and compare it with new before database updating, collect difference and apply to MYSQL.

Comment: The SQL query seems like it would work (although I'll probably do a select first, just to know which UIDs are missing). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start with a simple workflow like this:

1. loop through json collecting active UIDs
2. fetch working set from mysql using `where ID in(...)`
3. loop through working set looking for differences, applying changes
4. mark newly removed records using
    `set Removed = 1 where ID not in(...) and Removed = 0`

Comment: If only I could mark two answers as correct, but vp_arth beat you to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i. Import JSON nightly feed into a temp table.
ii. Compare temp table against real table.

iia. In real table not in temp table it was deleted
iib. In temp table not in real table it was added

You could place these into two separate tables

ItemsAdded
  ItemsDeleted

iii. Replace the real table with data from the temp table